# Stop AcceptTcpClient on CancellationToken

Tags: multithreading, sockets, .net-4.0, network-programming, tcplistener

Is there any way to in .net4 check for CancellationToken while accepting clients synchronously.

```
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //change this somehow to use check cancellation but keep this blocking
        TcpClient client = _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        var client= new myclient(client);
        _clients.Add(telemetryClient);
    }
```

The best I could do so far, isn't clean enough:

```
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var acceptTask = Task<TcpClient>.Factory.FromAsync(_tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient, _tcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient, null);
            var tokenTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    return;
                }, token);
            Task.WaitAny(new Task[] { acceptTask ,tokenTask}, token);

            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            TcpClient client = acceptTask.Result;//_tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            var client = new myclient(client);
            _clients.Add(telemetryClient);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it sufficient to just do 
Task.WaitAny(acceptTask, token)?

ie I'm not seeing why the tokenTask is required.

Also, if cancellation occurs and then the acceptTask suffers an exception, you might find that an 'unobserved exception' situation arises.  Consider using TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException to catch (and likely ignore) those.

-mike